# netbackup vxlogview bptm

Tags: netbackup

Does anybody knows how to get bptm logs with vxlogview? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible: http://seer.entsupport.symantec.com/docs/278572.htm

> Daemons that continue to use Legacy logging
>   A listing of daemons that use Legacy logging include, but are not limited to:

```
* NetBackup Master Server daemons (bprd, bpdbm, bpjobd, bpdbjobs, admin)
* NetBackup Media Server daemons (bpbrm, bptm, bpdm)
* NetBackup Robotic daemons (vmd, avrd, ltid and robotic daemons)
* NetBackup Client daemons (bpcd, bpbkar, tar)
```